# convert dictionary sentence and index into dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
{
The word ‘Women Empowerment’ itself implies that women are not powerful enough - they need to be empowered.: 0, This painful truth has been in existence for a long long time.: 1, It is in recent years that noticeable work started beginning to lift women out of the abyss of insignificance and powerlessness.: 2, The patriarchal society suppressed women’s freedom across the world.: 3, Women were not allowed to vote or even put forward any opinion.: 4, Women were confined to their homes.: 5, As time progressed, they realised that their life meant much more than just serving in the household.: 6, As more and more women started crossing the man-made barriers, the world began to witness the rise of women.: 7, Unlike men, women never try to stifle the voice of their opposite gender.: 8, They hold the hands of all the downtrodden people - men and women both - and they pull them out of misfortune as they try to improve their lives.: 9 }
```

I need to convert this dictionary into pandas dataframe with column sentence and index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the key value pairs then feed it into pd.DataFrame(). Finally transpose().

```
data = {v: k for k, v in data.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0]).transpose()
```

Comment: this will not write the sentence as a whole rather it put comma separated words of the sentence.

Comment: sure update your question to specify this criteria.